# fullcalendar v5.0.1: How to implement dayCellDidMount in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, hook, fullcalendar-5

Have someone example code for vuejs ? I need this to disable some dates.
Effectively, validRange not work for multiple range: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3746

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mestorf-bwjbl?file=/src/components/DayCellFC.vue

Here!

```
 dayCellDidMount(arg) {
   arg.isDisabled = true; // Cell disabled, like invalid range, not work why ?
   console.log("CELL", arg);
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear how the code shown has a relationship to validRange? Please explain in more detail, ideally with a specific example. It seem you're simply trying to do something which isn't supported - i.e. multiple valid ranges, but it's also not obvious how this relates to your dayCellDidMount code.

Comment: Also your codesandbox doesn't appear to work, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Hi! this is alternative solution (i have implemented) https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3125 but it's not clean: cell selectable, cell clickable, etc. When you have invalid range (validRange option), cells are disabled. I don't know why you can't see the codesandbox over